# How to store files in memory with java?

Tags: java, ftp, stream, binary, ascii

I am trying to implement a minimal FTP Server using java. On this server, I want all files to exist in memory only. Nothing should be written on disk.

Having said this, I have to create a virtual file system, comprised of a root directory, some sub-directories and files. A few of those will initially be loaded from the hard disk and then will only be handled in memory.

My question is: is there an efficient way to implement this in Java? Is there something that is preimplemented? A Class I should use? (I don't have access to all libraries: java.lang, java.io)

Assuming there is not, I have created my own simple FileSystem, Directory and File classes. I have no idea, however, how I should store the actual data in memory. Knowing that a file can be an image, a text file or anything else that could plausibly be exchanged with an FTP server, how should I store it? Also, there are two transfer modes that I should be able to use: binary and ASCII. So in whatever format I store the data, I should be able to convert them to some kind of binary or ASCII format.

I know the question is a bit abstract, any sort of hints as to where I should look will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this an assignment?

Comment: @MarcoZielbauer It is part of a bigger assignment yes. I hope this is irrelevant

Comment: No, this is not irrelevant. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Some hints. A file is nothing more than a byte block with a name. It's that simple. The main difference between ASCII and BINARY mode (in FTP context) is the handling of line endings. You should read [RFC 959: FILE TRANSFER PROTOCOL (FTP)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959).

Comment: @vanje I was reading the protocol from a different site and it was not complete apparently. This really helped. But it still does not answer my question...I get the file is a stream of bytes, but should I store it on memory simply as an array of bytes (byte[]). Isn't there some other java class that can do this more efficiently. How do I read the file byte by byte etc..

Comment: You shouldn't make it more complicated than it is. Why don't you create an InMemoryFile class with a file name and a byte array as fields? You can use ByteArrayInputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream to access the byte buffer. Why do you think it is inefficient to use a byte array? The limiting factor here would be the network communication.

Answer (score 0):

The data will be in memory unless written to the disk.

Assuming you have the relevant data stored in some variables then simply do not call any file writer and the variable will remain in java's stack/heap without being stored onto the filesystem.